# Find a pair of linear transformations that do not commute

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, linear-transformations

The problem statement is as follows:

> Suppose $\mathbb{F}$ is any field. Find a pair of linear transformations $S,T \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{F^{2}}, \mathbb{F^2})$ such that $ST \neq TS$

---

My attempt follows. Let $v = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ 
y \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{F^2}$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{F}$ and let our linear transformations $S,T$ be represented by the matrices $$A = A(S) = \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 
-a & 0 \end{pmatrix} \ \text{where}\ a \in \mathbb{F}$$ $$B = B(T) = \begin{pmatrix} b & b \\ b & 0 \end{pmatrix} \ \text{where}\ b \in \mathbb{F}$$

Then we have: $$S \circ T(v) = ABv = \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 
-a & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} b & b \\ b & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ 
y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 
-a & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} bx + by \\ bx \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} abx +aby \\ -abx -aby \end{pmatrix}$$ $$T \circ S(v) = BAv = \begin{pmatrix} b & b \\ b & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ 
-a & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ 
y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} b & b \\ b & 0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} ax \\ -ax \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} bax + (-bax) \\ bax \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ bax \end{pmatrix}$$

So, if we were to have $ST = TS$ that would be equivalent to: $$\begin{pmatrix} abx + aby \\ -abx - aby \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ bax \end{pmatrix}$$ Since $abx + aby = 0$ that implies $x = -y$. So then we would have $0 = bax$ which only happens if $b,a,x = 0$.

---

I keep running into this problem, where the matrices don't commute in general except for when any or all of the entries equal $0$. Would the solution be to consider elements of the form $\frac{1}{x}$ where we simply wouldn't allow $x = 0$? Or is there something, simpler or a more systematic approach to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

Matrix commutativity is a rare phenomenon.  If you think of a random pair of matrices, say $\pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0&0}$ and $\pmatrix{0& 1\cr 0&0}$, chances are they will not commute.

Comment: I figured that but the way the question was stated, specifically about how "$\mathbb{F}$ is any field", it made me feel like I needed to find a general set of matrices that do not commute. I was originally going to just pick $2$ random matrices with entries that are in the most elementary field (I've been exposed to, at least) $\mathbb{Q}$ so that they would work in any more complicated field and thus *any* field. Are you saying that would be an acceptable answer for this kind of problem? Perhaps I'm making it more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Got you.  Indeed, in the smallest field possible, namely $\mathbb F=\{0\}$, should you not worry about the fact that $1=0$, all matrices commute.  However, in all other fields, where  $1\neq0$, the likelyhood that two matrices,  whose entries are chosen in $\{0,1\}$, commute, is also very small.

Comment: No, $\{0\}$ is not a field. $1\neq 0$ is an axiom of field theory.

Comment: $\{0\}$ is a field for those who do not require that axiom ;-). However this is such a minor point that it is ridiculous to argue about it

Comment: @Jair, as you've seen I edited to account for your now deleted comment.  In any case, my point is not so much to exhibit a pair of non commuting matrices, but to say that a random pair is highly likely not to commute.

Comment: @Ruy: You cannot change the definition of field because you want to have $\{0\}$ as a field.

Comment: @Piquito. I certainly do have a very good answer to your comment but I will refrain from giving it.  It is really not worth it!

Comment: @Ruy: The idea that you may have a 1-element field is clearly inconsistent with the question since in that case there is just one matrix involved and it commutes with itself.

Comment: @Mark.  So you guys do insist in dwelling on this issue!  Ok, just don't expect me to participate.

Comment: @Ruy: Please, Ruy, don't leave people less brilliant than you without your “very good answer”. But refrain from qualifying an opinion about zero as "ridiculous" (consider that zero is a great cultural and scientific achievement of the human kind). Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

The solution it seems to me is to use elements that are, by definition, elements of any field ie $1$ and $0$ - you can guarantee you have them and you know enough about their arithmetic in the field to exemplify the matrices you need.